# make4ht force the beginning of the sentence on a new line, when the beginning of the sentence would be near the border of my window

Tags: tex4ht, html, make4ht

I convert my `.tex` into `.html` with the command

```
make4ht -ul hello.tex
```

but I see that the html language allows for the beginning of a sentence very near from the end of the screen. For instance, it is not rare to find the situation:
a `sentence1` which takes nearly all the screen, then `First-word-of-new-sentence` [on the same line as `sentence1`] then a new line continuing the new-sentence.

If I change the size of my window of my browser, I can put the `First-word-of-new-sentence` on the second line, but then it does not resolve the numerous other cases happening later in the `.html`.

**is there a trick to force the beginning of the sentence on a new line, when the beginning of the sentence would be near the border of my window ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for two reasons. First is that we can't detect beginning of sentences in TeX unless you provide explicit markup (think of `\sentence{Firs-word-of-sentence, rest of sentence`), the other is that even if we add some markup for sentences in the HTML, I don't think that there is a CSS declaration which would solve this request.

BTW, it happens also in PDF output of LaTeX, doesn't it?

Comment: yes it does happen sometimes in the beginning of the pdf.